# How to query a Firestore collection with an array filter?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I was doing a query to get information about the user. I want to save in a state the documents that contain the user's id, the user's ids are in an array within the document, my database is like this:

[image]

I was doing a query like this:

```
const loadingInformation = async () => {

        db.collection('channels').get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    if (doc.data()?.users?.includes(user.id)) {
                        setInformation([...information, {
                            id: doc.id,
                            data: doc.data()
                        }
                        ])
                    }
                })
            })

    }

 useEffect(() => {
        loadingInformation();
    }, [])
```

the problem is that it only brings me one document and this user is in more than two collections, also, when updating the page, a push is made but from the same document.

I also saw in the documentation that there is a request something like that, but it doesn't work for me:

```
await db.collection('channels').where('users', 'in', [[user.id]]).onSnapshot(snap => {
            setInformation(snap.docs.map(doc => ({
                doc
            })))
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In operator returns documents with field that can be equal to many values, not just one. For example, `.where('country', 'in', ['France', 'Germany'])` will return documents where country is equal to France or Germany. In operator is meant to be used on number and string field, not arrays. What you need is `.where('users', 'array-contains', user.id)`. If you want to search for more than one user use `'array-contains-any'` it works same as `'in'` operator but for arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, I did not know that this type of request could be made, now it works correctly.